# How to write HTML? [dependent drop down list using Material Design Components]

Tags: html, responsive-design, material-design

I'm a beginner in coding.
I would like to make dependent drop down list using Material Design Components.

I read official tutorial here.
https://material.io/develop/web/components/input-controls/select-menus/

However, I couldn't find how to write html.

This is the original html file which I wrote.

```
<div class="pulldownset">

    <!-- ========================================== -->
    <select class="mainselect" name="language">
       <option value="">language</option>
       <option value="en-US">US</option>
       <option value="en-GB">GB</option>
    </select>

    <!-- ================================================================ -->
    <select id="en-US" class="subbox" name="voiceId[]">
       <option value="">voice</option>
       <option value="en-US-Wavenet-A">en-US-Wavenet-A</option>
       <option value="en-US-Wavenet-B">en-US-Wavenet-B</option>
    </select>

    <!-- ================================================================ -->
    <select id="en-GB" class="subbox" name="voiceId[]">
       <option value="">en-GB</option>
       <option value="en-GB-Wavenet-A">en-GB-Wavenet-A</option>
       <option value="en-GB-Wavenet-B">en-GB-Wavenet-B</option>
    </select>

 </div>
```

I read https://material.io/develop/web/components/input-controls/select-menus/ and tried to write new html file, but couldn't.

I came up with some questions.

> Is "data-value" different from "name"?    Material Design Components
>   don't have  and , do they?

```
<div class="mdc-select">
      <div class="mdc-select__anchor demo-width-class">
        <i class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon"></i>
        <div class="mdc-select__selected-text"></div>
        <span class="mdc-floating-label">language</span>
        <div class="mdc-line-ripple"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="mdc-select__menu mdc-menu mdc-menu-surface demo-width-class">
        <ul class="mdc-list">
          <li class="mdc-list-item mdc-list-item--selected" data-value="" aria-selected="true"></li>
          <li class="mdc-list-item" data-value="en-US">
            en-US
          </li>
          <li class="mdc-list-item" data-value="en-GB">
            en-GB
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I searched the Internet "dependent drop down list using Material Design Components". However, I couldn't get an answer. Am I missing the point?

Could you give me any information or suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Sincerely, Kazu